# How does batch_size in this code control the number of output results?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a newbie, why do I output as many sets of data as I set the batch_size? The for loop in the function is not range(0,1000,batch_size), and batch_size is set to 10. Shouldn't it loop 100 times and output 100 sets of data?

```
    def create_data(w, b, nums_example):
        X = torch.normal(0, 1, (nums_example, len(w)))  
        y = torch.matmul(X, w) + b                     
        y += torch.normal(0, 0.01, y.shape)             
        return X, y.reshape(-1, 1)                      


    true_w = torch.tensor([2, -3.4])
    true_b = 4.2
    features, labels = create_data(true_w, true_b, 1000)  




    def read_data(batch_size, features, labels):
        nums_example = len(features)                         
        indices = list(range(nums_example))                   
        random.shuffle(indices)                              
        for i in range(0, nums_example, batch_size):          
            index_tensor = torch.tensor(indices[i: min(i + batch_size, nums_example)])   
            yield features[index_tensor], labels[index_tensor]  


    batch_size = 10
    for X, y in read_data(batch_size, features, labels):
        print("X:", X, "\ny", y)
        break
```

Comment: Why you say  it does not work? For me it  does loop 100 times for 1000 examples with a batch size of 10.

Comment: What I mean is: I don’t understand why the following for loop with break will only print 10 data, and deleting it will print 100 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `for i in range(0, nums_example, batch_size)`: goes from 0 to `nums_example`, but increments by `batch_size` in each iteration. This is how the `batch_size` controls the number of output results.

If `batch_size` is 10 and `nums_example` is 1000, the loop will iterate 100 times (i.e., 0, 10, 20, ..., 990). In each iteration, it picks `batch_size` number of indices starting from `i` and fetches the corresponding features and labels.

So, if you set `batch_size` to 10 and you have 1000 examples, you'll get 100 batches of data, each containing 10 examples. The number of batches is `nums_example / batch_size`.

You're printing only the first batch of data because of the `break` statement. If you remove `break`, it will print all 100 batches. So to me code is behaving as expected. The `batch_size` determines the size of each batch and the total number of batches will be `nums_example / batch_size`.

Comment: Sorry, I understand, I forgot the meaning of the operation of slicing the list indices[i: min(i + batch_size, nums_example)]